# Split dataset into group based on date+count [MSSQL 2012]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, grouping

I have a dataset within SQL Server 2012 that needs to work on the following principle:

> A "seat" allows for 8 results in a 6 month period from the first result. If there are more than 8 results within 6 months from the date of the first result then a new "seat" is given.
>
> If a result is created over 6 months from the date of the first result then a new "seat" is given

So I have the following data:

```
User    DateCreated
----    -------------
User1   2015-01-01 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-02 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-03 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-04 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-05 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-06 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-07 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-08 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-09 16:05:00
User1   2015-01-10 13:25:00
User1   2015-01-11 13:25:00
User1   2015-01-12 13:25:00
User1   2015-09-01 13:00:00 
User1   2016-04-01 13:00:00
User2   2015-01-01 13:25:00 
User2   2015-01-02 13:25:00 
User2   2015-09-01 13:25:00 
User2   2016-01-01 13:25:00 
User2   2016-05-01 13:25:00 
User3   2015-01-01 16:05:00 
User3   2015-01-02 16:05:00     
User3   2015-01-03 16:05:00
```

Based on the above rules, they could be split out into the following "groups"

```
User    DateCreated             Group
----    -------------           -----
User1   2015-01-01 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-02 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-03 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-04 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-05 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-06 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-07 16:05:00     1
User1   2015-01-08 16:05:00     1 /*8 results within 6 months from first row*/

User1   2015-01-09 16:05:00     2
User1   2015-01-10 13:25:00     2
User1   2015-01-11 13:25:00     2
User1   2015-01-12 13:25:00     2

User1   2015-09-01 13:00:00     3 /*created 6+ months after previous row*/

User1   2016-04-01 13:00:00     4 /*created 6+ months after previous row*/
----
User2   2015-01-01 13:25:00     1
User2   2015-01-02 13:25:00     1

User2   2015-09-01 13:25:00     2 /*created 6+ months after previous row*/
User2   2016-01-01 13:25:00     2 

User2   2016-05-01 13:25:00     3 /*created 6+ months after previous row*/
----
User3   2015-01-01 16:05:00     1
User3   2015-01-02 16:05:00     1
User3   2015-01-03 16:05:00     1 /*3 results within 6 months from first row, within the 8 result cut-off */
```

Which could then end up as

```
User        Seats
----        -----
User1       4
User2       3
User3       1
```

How would this be achieved within a SQL query, if at all?

--

Ok so the comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385655/1283391 is halfway there, I've modified the above expected output to account for the difference as my explanation was incorrect.

I don't think I need a **SUM**, more a **running total**.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT *,
         ( ( Row_number()OVER(partition BY [User] 
             ORDER BY [DateCreated]) - 1 ) / 8 ) + 1 AS rn, -- To group 8 records per user
                Lag([DateCreated])OVER(partition BY [User] ORDER BY [DateCreated])                     AS PREV_DATE
         FROM   Yourtable),
     INTR
     AS (SELECT *,
                Sum(Datediff(mm, Isnull(PREV_DATE, [DateCreated]), [DateCreated]))
                  OVER(
                    partition BY [User]
                    ORDER BY [DateCreated]) AS GRP -- To group the user based on Date difference 
         FROM   cte)
SELECT [User],[DateCreated],
       Dense_rank()
         OVER(
           PARTITION BY [User]
           ORDER BY rn, GRP) AS Groups
FROM   INTR
```

---

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE Yourtable
    ([User] varchar(5), [DateCreated] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Yourtable
    ([User], [DateCreated])
VALUES
    ('User1', '2015-01-01 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-02 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-03 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-04 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-05 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-06 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-07 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-08 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-09 16:05:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-10 13:25:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-11 13:25:00'),
    ('User1', '2015-01-12 13:25:00'),
    ('User2', '2015-01-01 13:25:00'),
    ('User2', '2015-01-02 13:25:00'),
    ('User2', '2015-09-01 13:25:00'),
    ('User2', '2016-05-01 13:25:00')
;
```

**Result**

```
+-------+-------------------------+--------+
| User  |       DateCreated       | Groups |
+-------+-------------------------+--------+
| User1 | 2015-01-01 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-02 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-03 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-04 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-05 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-06 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-07 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-08 16:05:00.000 |      1 |
| User1 | 2015-01-09 16:05:00.000 |      2 |
| User1 | 2015-01-10 13:25:00.000 |      2 |
| User1 | 2015-01-11 13:25:00.000 |      2 |
| User1 | 2015-01-12 13:25:00.000 |      2 |
| User2 | 2015-01-01 13:25:00.000 |      1 |
| User2 | 2015-01-02 13:25:00.000 |      1 |
| User2 | 2015-09-01 13:25:00.000 |      2 |
| User2 | 2016-05-01 13:25:00.000 |      3 |
+-------+-------------------------+--------+
```

To find the final result

```
Select [User],Max(Groups) as Seats
From INTR 
Group by [User]
```

Comment: That's really impressive, exactly what I need to work with. If I were to filter by date, I could that that after the **FROM   Yourtable** 
Is that correct?

Comment: Apologies but I'm unsure if the date difference grouping is working. If you change User2 - 2016-05-01 13:25:00.000 to User2 - 2016-01-01 13:25:00.000 then it should be in group 2 as it's within 6 months. Currently it shows as 3. Does that make sense? If the current rows date is 6 months after the previous rows date then its a new group.